# How to smash two HTML elements together with multiple tags

Tags: html

View image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxE4u.jpg

Although this is in PHP, I'm trying to (with HTML) get two words (which use the same class) to push next to each other without calling the class seperately or using the two words in the same if/if else function. I'm sure it's just a simple HTML element.

```
            <?php
                if (something){
                    echo "<p class='message'>hello</p>";
                }

                if (somethingelse){
                    echo "<p class='message'>world</p>";
                }
            ?>
```

As the comments aren't what I'm after, I'll show what I'm using:

```
            <?php
                if (!empty($message)){
                    echo "<p class='message'>" . $message . "</p>";
                }

                if (!empty($errors)){
                    echo "<p class='message'>";
                    foreach ($errors as $error){
                        echo " - " . $error . "<br />";
                    }
                    echo "</p>";
                }
            ?>
```

One statement or both at the same time  may prove true. Hopefully you can see why I can't wrap it all around an HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to do this

```
<p class="messasge"> <?php echo $message; ?> </p>
```

Comment: The class should only execute if something in the if statement has occurred

Comment: oh you want to the class to be added only when if condition is true?

Answer (score 0):

**RE-FIXED** according to updated specifications :

```
       <?php
            if (!empty($message)){
                echo "<p class='message'>" . $message;
            }

            if (!empty($errors)){
                if (empty($message) echo "<p class='message'>";

                foreach ($errors as $error){
                    echo " - " . $error . "<br />";
                }
            }

            if ((!empty($message))||(!empty($errors))) echo "</p>";

        ?>
```

- if JUST `message` is `true` it'll print `<p class='message'>MESSAGE</p>`
- if JUST `errors` is `true`, it'll print `<p class='message'>ERRORS</p>`
- if BOTH  are `true`, it'll print `<p class='message'>MESSAGEERRORS</p>`

Comment: The class should only execute if something in the if statement has occurred

Comment: @user1228907 anyway... if NEITHER something NOR somethingelse has happened, in the above case, maybe YES you'll have a `<p class='message'></>` thing, but with nothing in it. So, why does it matter? If you want the `class` part to appear under some condition, you'll definitely have to put it WITHIN that condition...

Comment: @user1228907 I have updated my answer to take this into account.

Comment: What my code does is gives both the texts the same class, but they are put into separate columns, I want them both in the same one.

Comment: @user1228907 Glad to hear that! (if you consider an answer as "correct", please mark it as an "answer"; this is the aim of SO anyway...) :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $message = "";
    if (something) $message = "hello";
    if (somethingelse) $message += " world";
    echo "<p class='message'>".$message."</p>";
?>
```

Comment: "$message" will be two different variables, I can't do it with the same variable as they are $message and $errors in what I'm coding

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want some variant on the following code:

```
<?php
    $output = '';
    if (something)
        $output .= 'hello';
    if (somethingelse)
        $output .= 'world';
    if ($output)
        echo "<p class='message'>$output</p>";
?>
```

For your example, you could replace all of the `echo`s in the first two conditions with appending to `$message`, then only output if there is something to output. There are numerous options but I think this is the most flexible / elegant.

In your case it can be simplified to,

```
<?php
    $output = $message;
    if (!empty($errors))
        foreach ($errors as $error)
            $output .= " - $error<br />";
    if (!empty($output))
        echo "<p class='message'>$output</p>";
?>
```

Comment: The class should only execute if something in the if statement has occurred

Comment: Well.. OK... the code is according to what the OP seems to need; but it definitely strikes me as an ugly piece of code (just a matter of taste I suppose)... 3 `if`s, etc for that?!

Comment: This answer is perfectly valid. It will not actually get into any of the if blocks if neither of the first two were true. $message remains blank for the third if block, and the <p> will never be echoed.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon Beauty is subjective (and more likely written in Haskell than PHP). I am not sure that the condition that nothing should be output if neither are true (which admittedly was added later) can be satisfied without considering 3 cases.

Comment: @ternaryOperator Beauty IS subjective. But, let me clarify : I wasn't trying to be... offensive, or anything. It's just that the initial requirements (now changed though) seemed to me as if they were forcing us to write bad (or weird) code... Now, (after the OP has updated the original post), it makes sense though... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the dl list is useful

```
<?php
  if (!empty($message)){
      echo "<dl class='message'><dt>" . $message . "</dt>";
      }

  if (!empty($errors)){
      foreach ($errors as $error){
        echo "<dd> - " . $error . "</dd>";
             }
   echo "</dl>";
     }
?>
```